# Get element from pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native, dom, webview

I'm trying to make an application to change SSID and password more easily using webview with react native. But when i get to apply the changes one popup shows up . I don't know how to get the id from popup's button. I'am using getelementbyid for other elements.

Edit: i found this post in stack where he changes the script inside a button. But i don't know how to do this when the script is inside a  tag :((((

Button:

```html
<button id="btnApplySubmit" name="btnApplySubmit" type="button" class="ApplyButtoncss buttonwidth_100px" onclick="ApplySubmit();">
<script>
document.write(cfg_wlancfgother_language['amp_wlancfg_apply']);
</script>Apply
</button>
```